# Magento encryption methods

Tags: php, magento, paypal, magento-1.6

I have two questions -

1. We know that magento stores api keys for paypal because it provides
   various payment   methods. But how does it store the API
   credentials? What are the encryption methods used? Where can one
   read more about it?
2. While we install magento we get a key which magento uses to encrypt
   passwords, credit card numbers etc. Does this key have to be unique
   for all installations ? Could it be possible that two installations
   have a same key?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for first question:

All the configuration data store into database table `core_config_data`. If any field in `system.xml` is specified with `<frontend_type>obscure</frontend_type>` then that data is saved with specified config path `<config_path>paypal/wpp/api_username</config_path>` rather than general path `payment/payflow_advanced/title`.

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM mage.core_config_data WHERE path LIKE '%wpp%';
```

And encryption method is magento itself developed using md5() and salt. To understand more about magento encryption method you have read this file `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Encryption.php` yourself. You will not found any where more about magento encryption method.

Hope it will help some extent!